# How can I create a css background that is split in 2 halves, and goes in different directions?

Tags: css, gradient

***Update**

I believe I wrongfully explained my question before. I would like to know if its possible to have a div with 2 gradients from top to half, from half to bottom that also has a gradient from left to right.

Div goes from color A1 to A5 on top half, while bottom half goes from A6 to A10.

At the same time, the top half of div goes from color A1-A5 to color B (Left to right)

While the bottom half of the div goes from color A6-A10 to color B (Left to Right)

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

***Update 2**

So basically this, as an example only:

**http://jsfiddle.net/guisasso/kF9QV/6/**

The correct gradient is displayed on the left div (I know I used tables for layout).
I would like The 2 divs on the right side to start with the same gradient as the div on the left (**from top to bottom**) and have a **left to right gradient** at the same time, so it would fade out to a white background at the end of that div.

**Except** it would be better, but not imperative, that the divs on the right were actually one single div.

Hope this makes the question clear.

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2" class="actualgradient">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="toplefttoright">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="bottomlefttoright">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>

<p>Example</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.horizontal 
{

background: #ffb76b; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffb76b 0%, #ffa73d 50%, #ff7c00 51%, #ff7f04 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffb76b), color-stop(50%,#ffa73d), color-stop(51%,#ff7c00), color-stop(100%,#ff7f04)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffb76b 0%,#ffa73d 50%,#ff7c00 51%,#ff7f04 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffb76b 0%,#ffa73d 50%,#ff7c00 51%,#ff7f04 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffb76b 0%,#ffa73d 50%,#ff7c00 51%,#ff7f04 100%);      /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffb76b 0%,#ffa73d 50%,#ff7c00 51%,#ff7f04 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffb76b', endColorstr='#ff7f04',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
 width:200px;
 height:100px;
}

.toplefttoright
{
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right, #FFFFFF 0%, #FFA73D 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #FFFFFF 0%, #FFA73D 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right, #FFFFFF 0%, #FFA73D 100%);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, left top, color-stop(0, #FFFFFF), color-stop(1, #FFA73D));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #FFFFFF 0%, #FFA73D 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #FFFFFF 0%, #FFA73D 100%);
width:200px;
height:50px;

}

.bottomlefttoright
{
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right, #FFFFFF 0%, #FF7E03 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #FFFFFF 0%, #FF7E03 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right, #FFFFFF 0%, #FF7E03 100%);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, left top, color-stop(0, #FFFFFF), color-stop(1, #FF7E03));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #FFFFFF 0%, #FF7E03 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #FFFFFF 0%, #FF7E03 100%);
width:200px;
height:50px;

}


.actualgradient
{
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFB463 0%, #FF7E03 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFB463 0%, #FF7E03 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FFB463 0%, #FF7E03 100%);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #FFB463), color-stop(1, #FF7E03));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFB463 0%, #FF7E03 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFB463 0%, #FF7E03 100%);
width:200px;
height:100px;
```

}

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Doesn't get much easier than this.. http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: @fred02138 nothing, I know how to apply gradients, just am not sure if it is possible to achieve what I need.

Comment: Could you add an image demonstrating what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you can't clearly explain what you need, how are we supposed to tell you whether it's possible to achieve? Do you have an image that shows what you're trying to do? I can't make any sense of your text about `A1 to A5 top to bottom at the same time A1-A5 left to right`; it read like 'bippity boppity boo boppity bippity boppity boo too' to me. An image would go a long way to clarify what you're asking (create it in an image editor if need be).

Comment: @KenWhite How would I know the question is not clear unless you let me know? bippity boppity! =]

Comment: I think you were told that when your first attempt was closed, and when @icktoofay asked if you could add an image. :-) As far as your edit, please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a link to jsFiddle. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; the link you posted isn't clickable, and your question is still meaningless if the link destination is unavailable for some reason. Put the meaningful part of your question **here**, where future readers have access to it. (SO isn't just for helping you solve your immediate problem.)

Comment: Are you going to have any content in the div?

Comment: @thgaskell On the one on the left, yes, on the one on the right, not for now, but that's why I would like it to be a single div, in case I come to add content in the future.

Comment: @KenWhite It was closed as duplicate. I have added the code, as you are correct about future users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply multiple gradients with different `background-position` and `background-size`.

Instead of having the two smaller gradients fade to solid color, you should change it to the rgba value with an alpha channel of `0`. Then overlay them on top of the larger gradient, that way they colors will blend together as you move across horizontally.

Note the render order, the gradients declared first will appear on the top of the others.

Also, added no `background-repeat` so the first gradient doesn't render again over the second gradient.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kF9QV/7/)

#### CSS

```
.actualgradient
{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, #FFA73D 100%),
                      linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, #FF7E03 100%), 
                      linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFB463 0%, #FF7E03 100%);
    
    background-size: 100% 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 100%;
    background-position: 0 0, 0 100%, 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably generate what you need using this site: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor.

Here is a quick (and very ugly) example I generated:

```
background: #fff832; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff832 0%, #ff28fb 50%, #ff28fb 50%, #000000 50%, #2414ff 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#fff832), color-stop(50%,#ff28fb), color-stop(50%,#ff28fb), color-stop(50%,#000000), color-stop(100%,#2414ff)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff832 0%,#ff28fb 50%,#ff28fb 50%,#000000 50%,#2414ff 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff832 0%,#ff28fb 50%,#ff28fb 50%,#000000 50%,#2414ff 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fff832 0%,#ff28fb 50%,#ff28fb 50%,#000000 50%,#2414ff 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff832 0%,#ff28fb 50%,#ff28fb 50%,#000000 50%,#2414ff 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fff832', endColorstr='#2414ff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you generate whatever background you want: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/